# C Program to find hypotenuse, hypotenuse found too big

Tags: c, hypotenuse

This is my first program in C. When I run this the hypotenuse it finds is huge. I enter side A and B as 2 and the output is `130899047838401965660347085857614698509581032940206478883553280.000000`. What did I do wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int die(const char *msg);
double hypotenuse(double side0, double side1);

int main()
{
    double a, b, c;
    printf("Enter side A: ");
    if (scanf_s("%1f", &a) != 1)
        die("input failure");
    printf("Enter side B: ");
    if (scanf_s("%1f", &b) != 1)
        die("input failure");
    c = hypotenuse(a, b);
    printf("The hypotenuse is %f\n ", c);
}

int die(const char *msg)
{
    printf("Fatal Error: %s\n", msg);
    exit(1);
}

double hypotenuse(double side0, double side1)
{
    return sqrt((side0 * side0) + (side1 * side1));
}
```

Comment: Enable compiler warnings.

Comment: `"%1f"` --> `"%lf"`

Comment: It looks like your `scanf_s()` field directives are incorrect.  The directive corresponding to a pointer to `double` should be `%lf`  (with lower-case letter ell), but you have used `%1f` (with digit 1).

Comment: Haha when I saw scanf_s("%lf") in class I thought it was a one I can't believe that was the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Simplification tip: `sqrt((side0 * side0) + (side1 * side1));` --> `hypot(side0, side1);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a typo in your `scanf()` conversion specifier: `%1f` should be `%lf` with an ell instead of a one.

These 2 characters look deceptively similar. For this reason, it is also recommended to avoid naming variables `l` or `ll`, `l1` etc.

The specifier `%1f` attempts to convert at most 1 byte from the stream as a floating point number and store the result into a `float` whose address is passed.  You pass the address of a `double`, so the behavior is undefined.
You can prevent this kind of silly mistake by increasing the warning level:

- `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror`
- `clang -Weverything -Werror`
- `cl /W3` or `cl /W4` or `cl /Wall`

Comment: `cl /Wall` works nicely too. (although the compiler warnings pale in comparison to those provided by `gcc`...)